# Getting the constructor property of a Class in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, class, constructor

Code :

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
var c:Class;
c = new Sprite()["constructor"];
trace(1,new c());
c = Sprite["constructor"];
trace(2,c);
trace(3,new c());
```

Result :

```
1 [object Sprite]
2 [class Class]
TypeError: Error #1115: Class$ is not a constructor.
    at Untitled_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()
```

So, getting the **constructor** property from a Class returns a Class which is not a costructor..? What's the meaning of this? Why is it not instantiable?

Comment: More like when you are doing this c = Sprite["constructor"];
 you are returning an object that has nothing to do with a Sprite. What exactly are you trying to do? ['constructor'] does not refer to the Sprite constructor.

Comment: In case 1 you're creating an instance of Sprite getting it's constructor property which is defined here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Object.html#constructor so you've created an instance, gotten the constructor property, which is a class and is in fact the Sprite class, you can create a new instance of that.  In the second case you're saying get the static property "constructor" on Sprite which is not the same as the instance/dynamic property "constructor".

Comment: It appears in the second case the value returned from the static property "constructor" on Sprite is of type Class http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Class.html as opposed to type Sprite (not sure what the intention/reasoning of that is though I imagine it has something to do with how it maintains static vars or something of that nature).

Comment: Well yes, my question is, what exactly is that Class returned?

Comment: I guess it points to the constructor of `Class`, but which is not actually accessible, so when you do `trace(3,new c())` then it crashes. The same thing happens when you do `var c:Class = new Class`, I think these 2 behaviors are the same.